# Python name 'data' is not defined

Tags: python

I am keep getting 'data' is not defined and I am new to python. I would like to know why I am getting name 'data' is not defined.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns



train = pd.read_csv('training.csv')
train.head()
train.shape 
train.isnull()
train.info()
train.isnull().sum()
train.dropna()
train['Street'].hist(bins=5)
cols = ['MSSubClass', 'LotFrontage', 'LotArea', 'OverallQual', 'OverallCond', 'MasVnrArea', 'BsmtFinSF1', 'BsmtFinSF2', 'BsmtUnfSF', 'TotalBsmtSF', '1stFlrSF', '2ndFlrSF', 'LowQualFinSF', 'GrLivArea','SalePrice']
corr = train[cols].corr(method = 'pearson')
corr
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (16, 12))
ax = fig.gca()
sns.set(font_scale = 1.5)  
heatmap = sns.heatmap(corr.values, annot = True, fmt='.2f', annot_kws={'size':15},
                  yticklabels = cols, xticklabels = cols, ax=ax, cmap = "RdYlBu")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
cols2 = ['BsmtFullBath', 'BsmtHalfBath', 'FullBath', 'HalfBath', 'BedroomAbvGr', 'KitchenAbvGr', 'TotRmsAbvGrd', 'Fireplaces', 'GarageCars', 'GarageArea', 'WoodDeckSF', 'OpenPorchSF', 'MiscVal', 'MoSold','SalePrice']

corr2 = train[cols].corr(method = 'pearson')
corr2
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (16, 12))
ax = fig.gca()

sns.set(font_scale = 1.5)  
heatmap = sns.heatmap(corr.values, annot = True, fmt='.2f', annot_kws={'size':15},
                  yticklabels = cols2, xticklabels = cols2, ax=ax, cmap = "RdYlBu")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
train['SalePrice'].describe()
train.boxplot(column=['SalePrice'])
plt.show()
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12, 20))
sns.boxplot(x='SalePrice', y='MSZoning', data=train)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12, 20))
sns.boxplot(x='SalePrice', y='LotConfig', data=train)
numerical_columns = ['MSSubClass', 'LotFrontage', 'LotArea', 'OverallQual', 'OverallCond', 'MasVnrArea', 'BsmtFinSF1', 'BsmtFinSF2', 'BsmtUnfSF', 'TotalBsmtSF', '1stFlrSF', '2ndFlrSF', 'LowQualFinSF', 'GrLivArea']

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (16, 20))
ax = fig.gca()  # Axes ª˝º∫
data[numerical_columns].hist(ax=ax)
plt.show()
sns.scatterplot(data=train, x='YearBuilt', y='SalePrice', markers='o', color='blue', alpha=0.6)
plt.title(' Scatter Plot')
plt.show()
sns.scatterplot(data=train, x='YearRemodAdd', y='SalePrice', markers='o', color='blue', alpha=0.6)
plt.title(' Scatter Plot')
plt.show()
```

I was expecting a visualization of my dataset excel file of training.csv. I do get a certain type of visualization, but however I am not sure if it is the correct visualization as I have an error that says data is not defined.

Comment: So where is your `data`? You used it without defining it.

Comment: Can you share a bit of dataframe data as an example?

Comment: @S.B, it is an argument to the seaborn boxplot function

Comment: @Mathpdegeek497 The one that causes problem is: `data[numerical_columns].hist(ax=ax)`

Comment: Thanks, @S.B, I got stuck thinking how come that line of code is producing errors and was reviewing sbn GitHub to see if there is any internal issue. Couldn't even see further. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The line of code data[numerical_columns].hist(ax=ax) is trying to plot histograms of the numerical columns in the data dataframe. However, the data variable has not been defined in the code provided, hence the error message "name 'data' is not defined".